# How to Create Find and Replace Function for Google Drive File Names with Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

Basically, I have a bunch of files in a shared google drive, let's say:
AA123_1.jpg
AA123_2.jpg
AA123_3.jpg
...
I am trying to get rid of all of the "123"'s and replace them with an empty space, or just replace "123_" with "_". I am not particularly familiar with google scripts (I do understand basic programming logic though), but yeah, basically I was wondering if anyone knows how I could make a script for this as there is a very large amount of files. Thanks ever so much.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested by [ask]

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to know just where to start. Google "google drive script bulk rename files" you will get a LOT of hits. Many will reference the [Bulk Renamer for Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bulk-renamer-for-drive/peboiggabkeljjdnbelmhbpnmonomngo) - about which I know nothing and have no opinion. You'll also find some general scripts such as [Bulk rename files in Google Drive](https://www.pbainbridge.co.uk/2019/09/bulk-rename-files-in-google-drive.html) which I tested and it does exactly what it says on the tin. if you need help with the latter, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In a given folder of Google Drive, you have a number of jpg images, each with a consistent file name structure ("AA123_y.jpg, where y is a single or multi-digit sequence number).

You want to rename these files to remove the third, fourth and fifth digits ("123").

For example, "AA123_1.jpg" -> "AA_1.jpg"; "AA123_1003.jpg" -> "AA_1003.jpg".

---

```
function renamejpgs() {

  /* 
  // A given Goiogle Drive folder contains jpg files.
  // The files have a consistent naming structure:
  // "AA123_y.jpg, where y is a single or multi-digit sequence number.
  //
  // The function renames the files by removing the third, fourth, fifth and sixth characters of the file name and substituting a single"underscore"
  // For example, "AA123_1.jpg" -> "AA_1.jpg"
  */
   
  // set the mime type/file type to be renamed
  var mimetype = 'image/jpeg';
  // get the folder ID; note the id is a string
  var folderid = "<<insert your folder ID>>"
  
  // getFoldersById = Gets a specific folders in the user's Drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)
 
  // get  files in this folder
  // myfiles is a File Iterator
  var myfiles = folder.getFiles();

  // loop through files in this folder
  while (myfiles.hasNext()) { 
  
    var myfile = myfiles.next();   
    var myname = myfile.getName();
    var ftype = myfile.getMimeType();
    // find the next file that matches the mime type
    var indexOfFirst = ftype.indexOf(mimetype);

    if (indexOfFirst != -1){ 
      // the next file was an image
    
      // edit the file name
      var fname = myname.replace("123_", "_");
      // update the file name
      myfile.setName(fname);       
 
    } //end if
  } // end while loop through main folder
  
  return false;
}
```

---

**Logic**

- `getFolderById()` is used to identify the specific folder on Google Drive
- `var mimetype = 'image/jpeg';` - this is a user defined variable; in this case the mime type is used to limit the files whose names will be changed to only jpg files.
- `getMimeType();` returns the mime type of a specific file.
- `ftype.indexOf(mimetype );` - a test to see if the file is the given mime type. `indexOf` returns "-1" if the index is not found, hence the IF statement.
- `var fname = myname.replace("123_", "_");` - uses the Javascript "replace" method to remove the third, fourth and fifth character and sixth characters which is ="123_". The script replaces the underscore because there is possibility of a file named "AA123_123.jpg", in which case the second "123" is not to be replaced.
- `myfile.setName(fname);`  - updates the file name

---

**Sample - Before**

[image: Before]

---

**Sample - After**

[image: After]

Note: the jpg files have been renamed, but the spreadsheet (which has a similar naming pattern) has not been renamed.