# How to do an internal search in google apps script and not just with a specific link

Tags: google-apps-script

I saw here [How to Create Find and Replace Function for Google Drive File Names with Google Scripts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/145769/how-to-create-find-and-replace-function-for-google-drive-file-names-with-google?newreg=e7771fa9399341a99a38f0eadf4ebafa) how to change Name in Google Drive
I want to know how to do an internal search (within folders) and not just with a specific link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Find files and rename them

```
function findfilesandrenamethem() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const name = ui.prompt("File Name","Enter File Name",ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
  const files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
  let fA = [];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    fA.push({name:file.getName(),id:file.getId()})
  }
  fA.forEach((obj,i) => {
    let n = i + 1;
    let repl = ui.prompt(`This is file ${n} of ${fA.length} files with the name: "${name}."`,"Enter Replacement Name",ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
    DriveApp.getFileById(obj.id).setName(repl);
  })
}
```